# EXE Run from Server

Tags: c#-4.0, thin-client

We are currently developing a multi-user WPF application.  Instead of installing this application on each client, we want to run the EXE from a server.  We don't necessarily want to use ClickOnce deployment, and we are most certainly not doing Web based applications.

Is there anything special I need to research and educate myself about in order to design and develop this type of application?  Is this possible using .NET and C#?

The goal is not to have to install anything whatsoever on the client.  And again, just because I know it'll be one of the answers given, there will be no ASP.NET nor any sort of web based anything involved.

Comment: Why avoiding the web based approach?

Comment: The majority of our customers who will be using this application do not want IIS, they don't want to have to allocate resources to the setup and maintenance of IIS, and as a company we chose not to do anything web related with the exception of a self-hosted WebAPI service or two.